# SOAP webservice call by ajax in phonegap error

Tags: ajax, web-services, cordova, soap, ripple

I'm having a problem with trying to set up a working web service in my application I'm making using Phonegap. I need to get data from an existing web service. I found that by using a simple ajax request, this should be working. Am I not using the ajax request correctly?

The web service I'm trying to call can be found here: http://ws.swinggift.com/SGServices.asmx

EDIT: I tested it on http://wsdlbrowser.com/ and I'm getting my xml file back, how does this site work ?

I'm working in the ripple emulator so I have a cross domain proxy.
I'm suspecting that my request header may be off ?

error that I'm getting:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (10:26:26:851 | error, network)
  at https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//ws.swinggift.com/SGServices.asmx%3Fop%3DGetVouchers

(I can't make my logon code public)

my test html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btnCallWebService").click(function(event) {
                    var wsUrl = "http://ws.swinggift.com/SGServices.asmx?op=GetVouchers";

                    var soapRequest =
                            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                            '<soap:Body>' +
                            '<GetVouchers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
                            '<logoncode>ICantGiveYouThis</logoncode>' +
                            '</GetVouchers>' +
                            '</soap:Body>' +
                            '</soap:Envelope>';

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: wsUrl,
                        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: soapRequest,
                        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetVouchers");
                            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
                        },
                        success: processSuccess,
                        error: processError
                    });
                });
            });

            function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
                if (status === "success")
                    $("#response").text($(req.responseXML));
            }

            function processError(data, status, req) {
                console.log(req.responseText + " " + status);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>
            Calling Web Services with jQuery/AJAX
        </h3>
        <input id="btnCallWebService" value="Call web service" type="button" />
        <div id="response" >
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
I don't know if it helps but if I do a 'GET' with the this code, I get the webpage in HTML format if I ask for the responseText

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>

        <!-- jQuery / jQueryMobile Scripts -->
            <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function soap() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://ws.swinggift.com/SGServices.asmx?op=GetVouchers', true);

                // build SOAP request
                var sr =
                    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                                '<soap:Body>' +
                                '<GetVouchers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
                                '<logoncode>something</logoncode>' +
                                '</GetVouchers>' +
                                '</soap:Body>' +
                                '</soap:Envelope>';

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                            console.log('done' + xmlhttp.responseText);
                            $("#response").text($(xmlhttp.responseXML));
                        }
                    };

                // Send the POST request
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetVouchers");
                xmlhttp.send(sr);
                // send request
                // ...
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap();" />
                <div id="response" >
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to modify Ripple proxy.js. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222701/400-error-calling-wcf-web-service-from-ripple-emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an emulator problem ... Working now with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `processData: false`. This flag is true by default and jQuery is converting your XML to string.

> [By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: wsUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: soapRequest,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetVouchers");
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
                    },
                    success: processSuccess,
                    error: processError
                })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I'm gonna keep trying with your contribution though.